# TypeError: Cannot read property ‘map’ of undefined on Plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I’m new in Javascript and Plotly. I have no idea how to solve the error message

> *[TypeError: Cannot read property ‘map’ of undefined]*

. I’m plotting a scatter plot with 2 sets of input data. I try to update the data setting and the error message is prompt for the last line of the code

> *[Plotly.restyle(‘view’, update);]*

as shown below:

```
trace1 = {
   x: xdata,
   y: ydata,
   mode: ‘markers’,
   type: ‘scatter’,
   text: cdata,
   marker: {size: 20}
}
if (!isNaN(cdata[1])){  
   var update = {
      marker: {color: cdata}
   };
   Plotly.restyle(‘view’, update);
}
else {  
   var update = {
     transforms: [{type: “groupby”, groups: cdata}]
   };
   Plotly.restyle(‘view’, update);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is you `map` function?

Comment: firstly, change the `‘’` to `'` and `“”` to `"`

Comment: Can't find any documentation on update having a `transforms` property - so, that could be something you're doing wrong

Comment: try `transforms: [[{type: "groupby", groups: cdata}]]`

Comment: I have changed all ‘’ to ' and “” to " and tried with transforms: [[{type: "groupby", groups: cdata}]] -> get the same error

Comment: Error it self describes issue. try to assign default null array to undefined variable.
eg. let arr = [];